# How can I manually uninstall Wine

Tags: apt, package-management, wine, dependencies

I have installed wine on mu computer the other day, but it seems that it inst properly installed. although I can open .exe files with the Wine Windows Program Loader, wine doesn't appear in the unity dash or in Ubuntu Software Center. I tried to remove it to properly install it again with

> `sudo apt-get remove wine`

but it said that the package was not installed. And now it doesnt let me install Wine because there are "unmet dependancies".

> `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>   wine : Depends: wine1.6
>   E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

How can I uninstall Wine so I can re-install it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running `sudo apt-get install -f` to resolve the unmet dependencies.